# NGinx is not adding refferer to access_log in case of cached paged

Tags: nginx, service-worker, nginx-config

We are using the default access_log that means without defining it and it includes "$http_referer" by default. It works fine when you navigate to our page from clean browser, but in case you have visited it and the browser using the cache, refferer is not exist in the log

it has log like this, with service worker response

`22.222.2.22 - - [22/Dec/2023:14:03:25 +0000] "GET /assets/config/environment.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.05575449523719733 HTTP/1.1" 200 324 "https://xxxxxx.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"`

and this is a proper log I expect to be

`22.222.2.222 - - [22/Dec/2023:14:17:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3700 "https://expected-ip.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"`